# Django - make list_editable only for some entries

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model *Person* which I want to have it in admin panel.

I created *PersonAdmin* with the following:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["Name", "LastJob", "CurrentJob", "status"]
    list_editable = ["CurrentJob"]

    class Meta:
        model = Person

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

*status* tells me if the person is dead or alive.

I want if status is dead -> CurrentJob to not be editable anymore.

Do you have any suggestions how can I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Django model admin provides a special method for this: `has_change_permission`. In your case it would be something as:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["Name", "LastJob", "CurrentJob", "status"]
    list_editable = ["CurrentJob"]

    class Meta:
        model = Person

    def has_change_permission(request, obj=None):
        if obj:
            return obj.status != 'dead'

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```